# помогите сделать Css фигуру

Tags: css, css3, svg, sass

помогите сделать такую фигуру, очень надо. буду признателен.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 7):

1) **css**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: boder-box;
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
}

.item {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 260px;
}

.item:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 0 solid red;
  border-top: 200px solid transparent;
  border-right: 100vw solid #cc0000;
  border-bottom: 50px solid #cc0000;
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```

2) **svg**

```html
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 537 223">

     <g transform="translate(295.57736,-33.172619)">
    <path
       id="rect4504"
       d="M -49.892836,107.25595 241.14883,33.172619 V 255.42262 H -295.57736 V 171.5119 Z"
       style="opacity:1;fill:#0000ff;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:evenodd;stroke:none;stroke-width:1;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-dashoffset:377.95275879;stroke-opacity:1;paint-order:stroke fill markers" />
    </g>
</svg>
```